# How can I consume other packages inside an NPM bin script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Let's say I am developing two NPM packages, named `web-app` and `shared-build-tools`. `shared-build-tools` is a dependency of `web-app`.

I want to create a bin script within the build tools that can be consumed within the app so I add the following to `shared-build-tools`'s `package.json`:

```
"bin": {
    "test": "test.js"
}
```

This will mean that `test.js` is available to `web-app` as an executable named `test`. This approach is documented in [the NPM blog](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/118810260230/building-a-simple-command-line-tool-with-npm).

## The problem:

The linked document advises that we use `shelljs` inside `test.js` to run commands, which does work but runs in the context of the web app, not the shared build tools. **Is there a way to run commands in the context of `shared-build-tools`?**

More specifically, `test.js` may contain the following:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

const path = require('path');
const shell = require('shelljs');

const webpackConfig = path.resolve(__dirname, 'webpack.config.js');
const command = `mocha-webpack --webpack-config "${webpackConfig}" "src/**/*.spec.js"`;

shell.exec(command);
```

But after `npm link`ing the two modules, the web app will report that `mocha-webpack` does not exist - because it doesn't exist when the context is the app. I do however have `mocha-webpack` as a dependency of `shared-build-tools` and would therefore hope there is a solution to this.

Any thoughts?

*Note that `src/**/*.spec.js` is nonsense right now - if/when I resolve this issue I will send this glob as a parameter from the web app.*